# Strange super script notation $^{(4)}R$ in the textbook Numerical Relativity

Tags: relativity, definition, notation, spacetime-dimensions

In Numerical Relativity by Thomas W. Baumgarte and Stuart L. Shapiro.

There are bunch of superscript $(4)$ over $T,\Gamma, R$
i.e. $^{(4)}\Gamma^a_{bc}$   _   $^{(4)}R_{abcd}$  _   $^{(4)}R$  ... (see example in page 5).

I thought it was just indicating it's $4$ vectors, where I encountered a sentence in page 8 saying "the superscript $(3)$ (on the left instead of on the right) in the above formula indicates the third time derivative..."

I flipped through the book and this notion continuously poped up, i.e. $^{(2)}ds^2$ ...

1. what does the superscript on the left mean? i.e. $^{(4)}R$
2. when the book said third time derivative(or higher), does it just mean $^{(3)}I =\frac{d^{(3)} I}{dt^{3}}$? But why it wasn't indicated in the indice. i.e. page 9 equation 1.50

Comment: “On the right instead of on the right”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @G.Smith says, it refers to 4-dimensionality.
In the first paragraph on page 27, it says
"Four-dimensional objects associated with $g_{ab}$ are denoted with
a superscript ${}^{(4)}$ in front of the symbol,..."

Answer (score 2):

It most likely indicates the number of dimensions. For example, $^{(4)}R$ indicates a 4-dimensional Ricci scalar.